Unable to make use of AnimateOnScroll from Primevue library in my Nuxt 3 composition API application
I have installed the PrimeVue library in my Nuxt 3 application with composition API and using it to create animateonscroll but for some reason it does not work at all. I tried using the Tree from Primevue and that works but for some reason, animateonscroll does not work.
I am using "primevue": "^3.52.0", and it's added to my package.json. Unable to understand why Primevue Tree works without any issue but animateonscroll does not work for me.
I am referring to their documentation and trying to create a fadeinleft:
Documentation: https://primevue.org/animateonscroll/
Code:
<template>
  <Button label="Check" />

  <Tree :value="nodes"></Tree>

  <div
    v-animateonscroll="{
      enterClass: 'animate-fadeinleft',
      leaveClass: 'animate-fadeoutleft',
    }"
    class="flex bg-primary text-primary-contrast shadow-lg justify-center items-center h-40 w-40 sm:h-60 sm:w-60 rounded-2xl animate-duration-1000 animate-ease-in-out"
  >
    <span class="text-3xl font-bold">fade-left</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Tree from "primevue/tree";
import Button from "primevue/button";
import AnimateOnScroll from "primevue/animateonscroll";

const nodes = ref([
  {
    key: 0,
    label: "test1",
    children: [
      {
        key: 0 - 0,
        label: "test0.1",
        data: "https://www.google.com",
        type: "url",
      },
      {
        key: 0 - 1,
        label: "test0.2",
        data: "https://www.google.com",
        type: "url",
      },
      {
        key: 0 - 2,
        label: "test0.3",
        data: "https://www.google.com",
        type: "url",
      },
      {
        key: 0 - 3,
        label: "test0.4",
        data: "https://www.google.com",
        type: "url",
      },
    ],
  },
]);
</script>

<style>
</style>


I am unable to get the fading from the left when I open my web page on the browser for this Nuxt 3 component. Am i missing something here? Because even Button component does not work for some reason only Tree works.
I have created a reproduction of the issue on CodeSandBox.
Please let me know what needs to be fixed.
Update 13 Aug: Even after trying different things it is not working any help or suggestions would be really appreciated. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Consider providing a [mcve] (use codesandbox.io or a similar service) to shed some light on your configuration details. Note nuxt integration and, more generally, primevue integration slightly varies across primevue major versions. Without those details, chances are nobody would be able to help. And, as a side-note, from what you shared so far, it's possible you're not loading the primevue CSS, which would explain the behavior.

@tao Thanks a lot for the response and sorry for missing out on the reproducible code. But I have created now. I have created a reproduction of the issue on CodeSandBox.
Please let me know what needs to be fixed.

The code sandbox is not starting for the moment because of an error in the code

@GeorgesA Thats strange because I just tried to open and it worked for me. Can you please trying again?

@GeorgesA Still unable to make this work, can you please let me know any suggestions or workaround? I have added my code sample to CodeSandBox

@tao Still unable to make this work, can you please let me know any suggestions or workaround? I have added my code sample to CodeSandBox

I checked it out and could not figure out what's wrong with it. But why don't you fork a working nuxt3+primevue+starter? I just linked the first one which showed up for me in google and it's not endorsed by either Nuxt or Vue. Also, there might be others. It might have stuff you don't want from Vue or Nuxt. But it looks like it's working properly.

@BATMAN_2008 I think you registered the transition directive the wrong way in your primevue plugin. Please refer to the documentation specific section: https://primevue.org/nuxt/#directives
